# SQL query to select with Range condition in source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a scenario to select the value from table where range condition is present in source table.

Like,

```
    TableA
    ID  value condition
    1   20      A-M
    2   50      N-Z

    Select value from TableA where condition = 'C%'

--want to select TableA value from TableB by passing person name starts with like,     

-- Here C is item name starts with 
-- Should compare with range (A-M) and return first row.
-- Condition column is varchar(3)
```

I have seen the solution on other way where range can be compared with input value, but here the range is present in the source table. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **[`QUOTENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function as

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE @Condition LIKE QUOTENAME(Condition);
```

This will be as

```
WHERE 'C' LIKE [A-M] --return True
```

**[Demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97e42577477960e38881e1a9bfbab118)**

**[Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1dbba916ad2ae1e5fe90b0a7a14367d8)**

Answer (score 3):

If I have understood what you are after correctly you can use

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.*
FROM TableB B
WHERE B.Name LIKE (SELECT CONCAT('[',condition,']%') FROM TableA WHERE ID =1)
ORDER BY B.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you should be structuring `TableA` as:

```
ID  value Lower  Upper
1   20      A      M
2   50      N      Z
```

Then you want:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where left(@name, 1) between a.lower and a.upper;
```

You can get this to work with your format, by doing:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where left(@name, 1) between left(a.condition) and right(a.condition);
```

But I don't recommend that.  Better to store the condition in two columns.

Comment: Thank you for response, I do not have much control on the TableA, is there any way to achieve this select with existing table structure

Comment: @PradeepH . . . That is the second part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always you should try to add data and DDL for setup correctly the test scenario, here my proposed solution:

```
DECLARE @SourceA AS TABLE
(
  ID  INT,
  Value INT,
  Condition VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @SourceA (   ID ,
                         Value ,
                         Condition
                     )
VALUES (   1 , -- ID - int
           110 , -- Value - int
           'A-M'  -- Condition - varchar(100)
       ),(2,250,'N-Z')


DECLARE @Alphabet VARCHAR(200)='A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z';


; WITH MyCTE AS
  (
   SELECT ID,Value,Condition, SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, PATINDEX('%'+ LEFT(Condition,1) + '%' ,@Alphabet),(LEN(@Alphabet)-PATINDEX('%'+ RIGHT(Condition,1) + '%' ,@Alphabet))+1) AS FormattedCondition
   FROM @SourceA
  )
  SELECT * FROM MyCTE
  WHERE MyCTE.FormattedCondition LIKE '%C%'
```